# Fourier Transform Computer Vision Textbook

Tags: computer-vision, fourier-transform

I am required extremely fast to fill the gap and learn Fourier Transform with application in Computer Vision.

It was easy to find mathematical aspects of Fourier Transform, but I am more interested in application in Computer Vision for a newbie with a lot of examples.

If you familiar with a textbook or have any other source of information about Fourier Transform well explained with examples in the field of Computer Vision, please share it with us.

Comment: I recommend you to read Gonzalez&Woods "Digital Image Processing".

Answer (score 2):

Thats funny,  I was exactly trying to fill the same gap.
I found the several sites which helped me

this is one of them : 
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm

Moreover , I recommend on creating a black image and playing with it.

e.g.

```
black = false(500,500);
black(10:40:end,:) = true;
black = imrotate(black , 45 , 'crop');
ffim = fftshift ( abs ( fft2 ( black ) ) );
lffim = log ( ffim ) ;
fs(lffim,[]);
```

Comment: Black image? Do you mean a black and white image?